# JavaScript loop compare string JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble with comparing a simple loop and if condition here, trying to compare a string from a return JSON file and compare it.
Here is my JSON file

```
"interface": [["enp1s0", "e4:3a:6e:09:bb:d3", "10.0.0.250/24", "fe80::e63a:6eff:fe09:bbd3/64"], ["enp2s0", "e4:3a:6e:09:bb:d4", "192.168.0.250/24", "fe80::e63a:6eff:fe09:bbd4/64"], ["enp3s0", "e4:3a:6e:09:bb:d5", "unavailable", "unavailable"], ["enp4s0", "e4:3a:6e:09:bb:d6", "unavailable", "unavailable"]]}
```

and this is my js code that tries to compare if the the ip address is defined to fill mt table

```
  function getinterfaces() {
    $.getJSON('/getips/', function(data) {
      //  document.getElementById("enp1s0").setAttribute("data-value", data.interface)

      for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        if (data.interface[i][2] === 'unavailable') {
          document.getElementById('enp' + i + 's0').textContent = data.interface[i][2];
        } else {
          document.getElementById('enp' + i + 's0').textContent = 'NOT ASSIGNED';
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I have a table to fill from the json file

```
......
<td><span id="en1ps0"></span></td> .....
 <td><span id="en2ps0"></span></td> .....
 <td><span id="en3ps0"></span></td> .....
  <td><span id="en4ps0"></span></td>......
```

Json
[image: Json return file]

Comment: The id indexing is inconsistent between your HTML output and the js references: `'enp' + i + 's0'` vs. `id="en1ps0"`. The first has the counter (`i`) after `enp`, the second after `en`

Comment: What is the issue you facing ?

Comment: I just figured it out !! it was a typo + the loop was wrong . the counter i should begin from 1 to 5 to include all the 4 interfaces .thanks you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

JS:

```
function getinterfaces() {
      $.getJSON('/getips/', function(data) {

        for (let interface of data.interface) {
          const name = interface[0];
          const ip = interface[2];
          const element = document.getElementById(name);
          if (element) {
            if (ip !== 'unavailable') {
              element.textContent = ip;
            } else {
              element.textContent = 'NOT ASSIGNED';
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

HTML :

```
<td><span id="enp1s0"></span></td>
<td><span id="enp2s0"></span></td>
<td><span id="enp3s0"></span></td>
<td><span id="enp4s0"></span></td>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time ,i just added a screenshot of my Json file that i m parsing